# How to keep app running in background mode

Tags: ionic3

i have built ionic app and i need a way to keep my app ruining in background,
i use set interval to send HTTP request but when i close the app 
it doesn't work

```
  constructor(
              public http: HttpClient,
              public platform: Platform ,
              public navCtrl: NavController, 
              private callLog: CallLog,
              private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode,
              private statusBar : StatusBar,
              private appService: AppServiceProvider,
              private uniqueDeviceID: UniqueDeviceID,
            ) 
          {
            var self= this
            if(this.platform.is('cordova')){
              this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
              this.getDeviceId()
              this.deviceId = localStorage.getItem('DviceId')
              this.callLog.requestReadPermission()
              this.backgroundMode.enable();
              this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
              this.statusBar.styleDefault();
              setInterval(function(){
                self.backgroundMode.enable()
                self.postLogs()
              }, 6000)
            })
          }
          }
```

Comment: Can you add more details on "it doesn't work"?

Comment: when i press home button in android  set interval stop!

Comment: it is stop when i switched to another app